# Static variables in WCF Service lose values

Tags: wcf, static, reset

I have a WCF Service hosted by IIS 7.5 with static variables in it.
The Service is called sporadical, and for a while the variables keep their values.
But at some time they lose the values and get re-initialized - and I don't know why.
First I thought that was because of the Application Pool recycling, so I changed the recycling interval to infinite - but it still happens.
I observed the w3wp.exe in task manager: It still has the same PID after the static variable reset happened, new calls to the service go to the same worker process - so we can exclude the app pool recycling, right?
So what happens there and how can I fix it, any ideas?
The Service uses

`[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]`

Here the results of several tests I made:
It even happens when I prevent a call from returning by Thread.Sleep(), so the idle timeout of the worker process (set to 20minutes) can be excluded as well? Sometimes it runs serveral hours before the reset of the statics take place.
But it seems the "old" waiting thread still exists because I can made it continue running by an external signal (SQL table entry that is being checked after X seconds between the sleeps in infinite loop).
Its like "another world" where the static variables still exist and the Threads keep on running, but each new call from a random time on runs in a new world with new variables...

Anyone a solution to this?

28 august 2014
No ideas to this thing?
Several tests show: There is not a real "reset" taking place but at some unknown/random time when I make a service call (for testing) the static constructor is being called and the static variables are set to their inital values. As if the application pool was recycled before. But it didn't - I observed the event log (Filter: Source "WAS") - no recycling.
What the hell is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Static members are actually per AppDomain, rather than per-thread or per-Application Pool. Off the top of my head I don't know how WAS creates AppDomains for hosting WCF service instances, and I'm not sure where I'd look to find out either, but it strikes me as something that WAS can do precisely what it likes with and is not meant to be relied upon.

I may add an edit later if I get around to doing some more research, as this is a somewhat interesting question. May I ask *why* you're using static variables? Sounds like asking for trouble, in my opinion.

Comment: On Application_Start (Global.asax) I load data from SQL to some static variables so that each call of the service can access this data without doing a sql request every time. I dont think its that unusual to do so. But as I said, at some time the static constructor is called (again), the variables are reset to default, but NO recycle happened (then they would have the correct values because of Application_Start).